# Error: Could not find or load main class filename Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: filename

Tags: java, class, load, program-entry-point, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to compile my java code, but it's not compiled.
I'm commanding `javac File.java`

**`File.class` class file is not created yet, but my program is working perfectly.** What kind of problem is thik

Comment: Is it possible to add the source of File.java? And also how you are trying to run it?

Comment: javac File.java then enter, I know that javac will compile my File.java to Fila.class but without class file my program is run, any class file is not created yet :(

Comment: but there are no answer that I'm finding right now.

Comment: @MDMahbubSK *"I know that javac will compile my File.java to Fila.class"* Not always, see answer below. --- *"but without class file my program is run"* `javac` will never run the program, only compile it. In Java 11 or later, you can use `java File.java` (`java`, not `javac`) to compile and run the program in one operation, which will not create a `.class` file on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

***TL;DR** It is most likely that the `File.java` file contains a non-public top-level class of a different name, so the compiler created a `.class` file with the actual name of the class. Rename the class or the source file, so the names match.*

---

More than 99.999% of the time, `javac File.java` will create a `File.class` file if compilation completes without error, but that is not always the case.

A `.java` file can contain many classes, and each class is compiled to a `.class` file named after the class. E.g.

`File.java`

```java
class A { // top-level class
    class B { // nested class
    }
    void x() {
        class C { // local class
        }
        new Object() { // anonymous class
        };
    }
}
class D { // top-level class
}
```

This will create the following files:

```
A.class
A$B.class
A$1C.class
A$1.class
D.class
```

As you can see, no `File.class` was created.

When compiling from the file system, which is pretty much always the case, the following rules are applied by the compiler:

- There can be at most 1 top-level class that is `public`.
- If the `.java` file contains a `public` top-level class, the `.java` file must be named the same as that `public` class.

General recommendations:

- Have only one top-level class in a `.java` file.
- Even if the top-level class is not `public`, name the file after the class.

The two recommendations help ensure that both the compiler and us mere humans can find the source file containing a class.